# Funcionamiento de un show message Dialog

Tags: java

tengo una pregunta sobre un método y ojala me puedan ayudar.

Ya se utilizar el método `showMessageDialog`, pero lo que no entiendo es porque se tiene que colocar "null" antes de el texto que quieras que aparezca.

```
showMessageDialog(null, "Hola Stackoverflow");
```

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La documentacion del [showMessageDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-) indica que ese valor null es el parentComponent.

```
showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message)
```

> **parentComponent** - determina el Frame en el que se visualiza la
>   ventana de diálogo; si tiene valor null, o si el parentComponent no
>   tiene frame, se utiliza un marco predeterminado.